# Laravel Response Codes & Message

Tags: php, laravel, validation, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Laravel 5.3 and https://github.com/1000hz/bootstrap-validator

I am checking the users' email against my Database in Laravel to check if the Email is in use or not.

The docs on Bootstrap Validator states to return a 200 if the Email address is fine (i.e doesn't exist) and return a 4xx error if it does.

In my Laravel function, I am doing the following :

```
public function check_email(Request $request)
{
    // Email Address
    $email = User::where('email', $request->input('email'))
            ->take(1)
            ->get();

    $email = $email->toArray();

    if(empty($email))
    {
        return response()->json(['Email Not Taken'], 200);
    }
    else
    {
        return response()->json(['Email In Use'], 400);
    }
}
```

Now when I run the validator, It's not showing the message. Is this because Laravel is stricter on its response codes? Or am I just doing something wrong?

My HTML code is as follows :

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                    <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" placeholder="Email" data-remote="/validate-email" data-error="Please enter your Email Address" required="required">
                                    @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                        <span class="help-block">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                         </span><!-- /.help-block -->
                                    @endif
                                    <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                            </div><!-- /.form-group -->
```

How do I go about setting a 4xx response with a message in Larvel 5.3?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, don't check if the user exists via a query use Laravel's validator class https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation it has already done this work for you, see: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-unique

Secondly, check out this library which is pretty much doing what you need already: https://github.com/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation

Answer (score 4):

You have to validate, either in your controller or create a request class

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation

```
public function check_email(Request $request)
{
    //validate 
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|unique:users',
    ]);

    // Email Address
    $email = User::where('email', $request->input('email'))
            ->take(1)
            ->get();
}
```